# Xcode Core Data - Convert UITextField value to NSDate and save in core data as date

Tags: nsstring, nsdate, textfield

iam using Xcode 4.6, and have a view with an UITextField where i can set the date. The value is NSString and i can see it with NSLog. Now i want to save this date in coredata. XCdatamodel has a entity with one attribute myDate Date. When i convert the NSString to NSDate then i allways get null. Whats wrong with my code ?
Thanks

My Code:

```
//CoreData
AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
context = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];

//Convert string to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Berlin"]];

NSDate *dte1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.myDate_Textfield.text];
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.myDate_Textfield.text];
NSDate *dte2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

//Output
NSLog(@"Value 1: %@",dte1);
NSLog(@"Value 2: %@",dte2);
NSLog(@"Value 3: %@",self.myDate_Textfield.text);
NSLog(@"Value 4: %@",myDate_Textfield.text);
NSLog(@"Value 5: %@",dateString);

//Save
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyDates" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[entity setValue:dte2 forKey:@"myDate"];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

The Output:

Value 1: (null)
Value 2: (null)
Value 3: 15.09.2014
Value 4: 15.09.2014
Value 5: 15.09.2014

Comment: The date format does not match the text you're trying to convert. Search for date format questions and answers.

Comment: Yes .. i get now the date, not formatted like above but i get it. thank you very much for your help, a few hours learning core data and i forgot the easy things in programming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+(NSString *) stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
return [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

}

look your date format is incorrect for provided string. And upgrade your xcode. You won't be able to submit apps using xcode 4.6, it's old dated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it now to "dd.MM.yyyy"

the output is : "2014-09-14 22:00:00 +0000"

ugly when i look to the database the inserted value for myDate is : "432424800"